# How can I increment a select element id "task_list0" by 1 for every cloned element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, clone

I have a basic select element with an id "task_select0" and when I want to increment the 0 by 1 for every element cloned.

This is the code used to clone the div containing the select element.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.rb', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();

    });

    var c = $(".measurchild:last").attr("id").replace('measurchild', '');
    var cloned;
    var barcode = $("#mybarcode").val();
    
    $("#measurMore").on('click', function() {
        cloned = $('#measurchild' + c);
        $("#measurchild" + c).clone(true).attr('id', 'measurchild' + (++c)).insertAfter(cloned);
        $(".measurchild:last").find('input, select, textarea').val('');
        $(".measurchild:last").filter(":selected").remove();
        $(".measurchild:last").find('input[type=hidden]').remove();
        $(".measurchild:last").find('input[id=task_list]').val('');
        $(".measurchild:last").find('input[id=mybarcode]').val(++barcode);
});
```

The code I've tried to use only increments the 0 to 1 and then it stays 1 for all other cloned elements.

```
var task_id = $("#task_list0").attr("id").replace('task_list', '');
$(".measurchild:last").find('select[id=task_list' + task_id + ']').attr('id', 'task_list' + (++task_id));
```

Comment: your question would certainly be easier to understand if you added a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as recommended... without neglecting the fact that it will increase your chances of getting an answer..

Comment: Short answer: Don't. A *much* better approach is to not use any `id` in repeated/cloned content. Just use common `class` attributes on it, and then relate the elements to each other when any events occur using DOM traversal methods (ie. `closest()`, `find()`, `siblings()` etc)